# Dieharder test with binary file

Tags: random, statistical-test

I have a binary file containing 10^8 binary digits. I want to give it input as 100 sequence each of 1000000 bits in dieharder test .
I have given the command as
`dieharder -g 201 -f pseudoseq202.bin -a`
But all the tests fails. I think I need to specify the sequence length. Please help me how to specify the sequence length.

for the command
`dieharder -g 202 -f pseudoseq202.bin -a`

it is giving
`file_input(): Error: Wrong number of fields: format is 'fieldname: value'`

Please help how to perform dieharder test on binary file.

Comment: please study `man dieharder` (esp. the `-f` option, ...you can also "pipe" to stdin, ... `-n` looks like the "sequence lenth")

Comment: ...`-g` controls the "test", where `"...200 stdin_input_raw     |201 file_input_raw      |202 file_input  " ... https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

Comment: ..and I'm not sure how it behaves, but `-a` (all test) *and* `-g X` (test X only) is contradictory..